# How to edit a table in GRASS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector, attribute-table

How do I edit a table in GRASS?  When importing a vector into GRASS from QGIS, all the attributes are lost and I need these to continue with my analysis.

Comment: That is not normal behaviour in my experience.  Even where field names start with numbers I notice Grass just prepends an x to the name.  So, can you provide any additional information?

Comment: When I import a vector file consisting of a series of points into GRASS from QGIS, all the attributes in the original file are removed.  Only one column, named 'Cat' (for category I suppose), remains, and each point is assigned a number.  I used GRASS Tools - File management - Import Vector (v.in.ogr.qgis).  Shuffling or removing columns does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can bulk edit tables using the module [db.execute](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/db.execute.html) with SQL statements. You can edit attributes interactively when you are in 'edit mode' with the module [d.what.vect](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/d.what.vect.html)

However, as MappaGnosis correctly mentioned, this is abnormal behaviour. Can you specify the command you used to import the vector?